# why are these entropy inequalities similar

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

I have two inequalities for the Shannon entropy
$H(y)=-\sum{}y_{i}\log{}y_{i}$, where the $y_{i}$ are the $n$
coordinates of a point in an $n-1$-dimensional simplex with
$\sum{}y_{i}=1$ (think of $y$ as a probability distribution on a
finite outcome space).

$$
\mbox{(i) }H(y)<\frac{1}{n}\sum\left(\log{}y_{i}\right)-\log\frac{1}{n^{2}}
$$

$$
\mbox{(ii) }H(y)>\log\frac{4}{n}-\sum\left[\left(\frac{3}{2}y_{i}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)\log\left(y_{i}+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]
$$

In the attached diagrams, the $y$ that fulfill these equations are in
red and the remaining points in the simplex are in green. The two sets
are not the same (the second one is slightly larger), but they have the same shape and are very similar.
Why? (I came across these looking at some interesting properties of
the Kullback-Leibler divergence, for example its violation of the
triangle inequality.)

[image: Subset of the simplex fulfilling (i).]

[image: Subset of the simplex fulfilling (ii).]

Comment: Note that the greater than and lesser than signs are pointing in the opposite direction in (i) and (ii) for H(y). That should lend an interesting flavour to this question. Generally, the farther to the centre a simplex point is, the higher its entropy H(y), so in (i) the RHS must be an even more sensitive measure of something akin to entropy.

Comment: n=3 in the diagrams

Comment: How are those inequalities deduced?

Comment: I was playing around with two properties I want the KL divergence to have -- one to be asymmetrically transitive (if dkl(a,b)-dkl(b,a)>0 and dkl(b,c)-dkl(c,b)>0 the dkl(a,c)-dkl(c,a)>0), the other to be greater towards less entropic probability distributions than more middling probability distributions. But it turns out that the KL div only has these properties when (i) and (ii) are fulfilled, respectively.

Comment: Pardon me, I meant to say "when (i) and (ii) are NOT fulfilled" -- it's on the complement of the "flower" in the diagram that dkl behaves normally.

Answer (score 0):

The greater and smaller sign are just unintuitive because you almost have $\frac{3}{2}H(y)$ on your right-hand side of (ii).

In fact, your (i) is equivalent to
$$\log \frac{1}{n^2}< \sum (y_i+\frac{1}{n}) \log y_i$$
while your (ii) follows from
$$ 2 \log \frac{4}{n} < \sum (y_i+\frac{1}{n}) \log (y_i+\frac{1}{n})$$
So your inequalities are very similar. As long as you don't want to conclude something more interesting, I don't think that there is more to it.

Comment: Let me call your two inequalities (K) and (KK). My (i) is indeed equivalent to your (K). But your (KK) is always false for n=3 and can therefore not be implied by (ii) which is true for some y in the n=3 scenario. (KK) is always false because the LHS is positive for n=3 and the RHS is negative for any n (a simple consequence of H(y)>0 for all y). I like your strategy, though, to make these two inequalities look alike -- that's exactly what I was shooting for, so thanks for trying.

Comment: Sorry, my inequality implies your result (ii) not the other way around. And although I expect that (KK) does not hold for any $y$ and $n=3$ this does not follow from the (usual) positivity of entropy (we don't use a pmf here but modify it by $+1/n$ which might result in negative values, at least I'm not aware of this positivity result)

Comment: thanks KoliG -- if I find out more I will post ...